# Regex to match a 2-digit number in Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

```
multiplier_h = $item.attr('class').match(/item-h(\d)/)
```

it matches `item-h3` class correctly but if it is `item-h12` then it just matches `item-h1`

so what should be change in above code to match 2nd digit also.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern like this will match a one or two digit number

```
/item-w(\d\d?)/
```

And a pattern like this will match a number with one or more digits:

```
/item-w(\d+)/
```

But in general, you can use `{n,m}` to match any number of digits from *n* to *m*. For example, to match anywhere from 1 to 5 digits:

```
/item-w(\d{1,5})/
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Because you can have more than one class I would recommend to match the neighbouring spaces and pad the subject,
2. To make it more generic, you can match as many digits as it can find, so that it will match `item-h100` as well.

So:

```
var str = ' ' + $item.attr('class') + ' '; // pad with spaces

multiplier_h = str.match(/\sitem-h(\d+)\s/);
```